# Am I setting up my SharedPreferences correctly to visit login page only once?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sharedpreferences

Whenever I run my activity in the emulator, it always takes me to `MainActivity` (if not logged into facebook then goes through `FacebookLoginFragment`) and then `ProfileActivity` where `ProfileActivity` is created twice (still trying to figure this one out). I am still trying to understand the `SharedPreferences` class, so would appreciate someone explaining that to me!

**Ideal Scenario**

- If app is launched first time `MainActivity` launches, user is logged into facebook and directed to `ProfileActivity`
- `MainActivity` is killed in case user hits back button on android
- If user exits app and resumes at a later time it should launch at `ProfileActivity`

**Problem**

- Is my code setup correctly?
- How would I set it up correctly, so that login page is only visited once?
- Would implementing an `onResume()` method in `MainActivity` help?

Code is here:

**First activity `MainActivity`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private FacebookLoginFragment mainFragment;

protected LoginButton fbLogin;

private ImageView splashLogo;
protected Animation anim;

private static final String FIRST_LAUNCH = "first_launch";

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = prefs.edit();
    Intent i;

    //Assume false if the key does not yet exist
    if (prefs.getBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, false)) {
        editor.putBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            //Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new FacebookLoginFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            //Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (FacebookLoginFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }

        splashLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.appLogoFixed);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    } else {
        editor.putBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, true);
        editor.commit();
        //Go to profile page
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus)
        splashLogo.startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**Second Activity: `ProfileActivity`:**

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {
protected ProfilePictureView profilePicture;

private TextView userInfoTextView;
private String userId;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_facebook);

    Intent i = getIntent(); //Grab the intent from previous activity
    userId = i.getStringExtra("Fb_id");

    profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    profilePicture.setProfileId(userId);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `FIRST_LAUNCH` variable is little bit confusing for me as I expected it to be `true` on first start, because it's not yet set. And later set it to `false`, because it's not "first launch" anymore.

Anyway what I see, in first block of your code in MainActivity > onCreate, you set

`editor.putBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH, true);`

but you probably forget to execute `editor.commit()`, so your new preferences are never saved.

**EDIT**: just very short explanation. Seems you understand `SharedPreferences` correctly. It's just important to keep in mind, that till you call `editor.commit()` all changes are not saved!! If you do not call `commit`, you changes will be lost.

Comment: well that was simple and thank you for explaining it to me! Menion any idea how to close the `MainActivity` activity when it opens `ProfileActivity`? I thought I had this covered in my code but `MainActivity` is still there when I hit back button.

Comment: perfect, you are welcome. Are you sure about fact that `MainActivity` remains active? Because `finish()` should close it correctly. Only what i may suggest to try, is to call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` before your if/else block. Even if you immediately `finish()` your main activity, `super.onCreate()` should be called to keep correct activity lifecycle (`onCreate()` > `onDestroy()`). Hope this helps.